# Is more robust to digit cancellation the sum operator or the mean operator?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

*Note: this question is not strictly related to Matlab or any other environment (even though I would prefer that you refer to my Matlab code).*

I've `n = 10000` equally spaced elements between `-pi` and `pi` in an array produced like this (in Matlab):

```
n = 10000;    
x = linspace(-pi, pi, n);
```

Then I create a second array `x_r`, which is basically contains the elements of `x` rounded to the third decimal place:

```
x_r = chop(x, 3);
```

Then, I calculate the `sin` of all elements of `x` and I call the resulting array `y`. I do the same for `x_r`.

```
y = sin(x);
y_r = sin(x_r);
```

Now, I try to sum all elements of `y` and then all elements of `y_r`, that is:

```
s = sum(y);
s_r = sum(y_r);
```

If I try to print `s` and `s_r` with `100` decimal digits after the dot, I obtain these huge numbers (and probably the first one is not finished):

```
s = -0.0000000000003170828901848210175171876477281318270923932134408573801920283585786819458007812500000000
s_r = -0.0000000000001331495677603378169351344695314764976501464843750000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Now, I want to find the mean of `y` and `y_r`, which I save respectively in `m` and `m_r`:

```
m = mean(y);
m_r = mean(y_r);
```

If I try to print `m` and `m_r` with 100 decimal digits, I obtain other two huge numbers:

```
m = -0.0000000000000000317082890184820990794524483366356918770088064486473850012160369260527659207582473755
m_r = -0.0000000000000000133149567760337822432508902790402516613129923689416538035157344666004064492881298065
```

My question is (as the title of this question indicates) which of the two operations is more robust to digit cancellation, the `sum` or the `mean` operation? And why?

My guess is that the mean operation is **less robust** to digit cancellation because it does more calculations, but I'm not sure, and I would not know if this would even be a right explanation. From the results, I'm not able to deduce anything useful honestly.

Comment: Mathematically, the only difference between `sum` and `mean` is that the latter involves a single additional division by a (in your case) moderate-sized number, so the stability properties can't be very different. Without knowing how Matlab implements the `mean`, it's hard to say much more -- but there are more stable approaches than the simple "sum-and-divide" approach, see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918641/choice-of-algorithm-for-incremental-floating-point-mean-java

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to realize is that reality doesn't work in decimal. And `sin(x)` in particular has no respect for decimals - it works in radians. So when you truncate `x_r` by up to `0.001`, that really is 6.36619772368E-4'th of a right angle.

When I then see that `y_r` has so many trailing zeroes, I assume there is a massive loss of precision. This probably is because MATLAB has to revert to direct numerical approximation with finite precision, while the non-rounded version allows a more direct formula.

This means digit cancellation is just straight-out irrelevant in the second case.

Comment: @Kirill: Of course - with one bit that would be one digit (0.5), with 2 bits 2 digits (0.25), and in general with N bits you need N digits. But note that these  results are the outcome of `sin(x_r)`, in contrast to `sin(x)` so there's a definite difference in precision used. The non-rounded example appears to use more than double precision, or possibly another closed-form formula.

Comment: Note that `s_r` is *exactly* $153511\times 2^{-60}$, and `s` is exactly $1570118422128477\times 2^{-92}$, so we're just looking at the finite decimal expansions of some floating-point numbers. I don't think the trailing zeros say anything about lost precision. Since the sum would be $0$ in exact arithmetic (the summand is antisymmetric), we're just looking at accumulation of different roundoff errors.